# System Colours - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, colors, system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why don't WPF themes use SystemColors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828587/why-dont-wpf-themes-use-systemcolors)

I have built an application and defined most if not all the colours manually for text / textboxes / backgrounds etc. However, how can I get this to reflect across that if the Windows theme is changed to something like High Contrast, my app will convert and still be usable visually in such scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

The best thing is to not touch the defaults. You can, however, use the system colors in your XAML files, too, like that:

```
Background="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveCaptionBrushKey}}"
```